# How do I obtain the column of my CSV File?

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to obtain the last column of my CSV file. I tried using getline and the stringstream but it doesn't get the last column only

```
stringstream lineStream(line);
    string bit;

    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {


        stringstream lineStream(line);
        bit = "";

        getline(lineStream, bit, ',');
        getline(lineStream, bit, '\n');
        getline(inputFile, line);
        stringVector.push_back(bit);
    }
```

My CSV file:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,no
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,yes
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,no
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,yes
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,no
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,yes
```

Comment: Several ways.  You could just loop with `getline(lineStream, bit, ',')` -- the last string read will be the last field.  Or you could use `std::string::rfind` to find the last comma and `std::string::substr` to retrieve it from 1 after that position.  This is kinda equivalent to `std::string::find_last_of`, so that's an option.  Or you could use `std::regex` (overkill).  Probably others.  Take your pick.

Comment: @paddy Sorry is it something like this with the while loop? `while (getline(lineStream, bit, ','))
 {
  getline(lineStream, bit);
  bit = "";
  cout << line;
  
 }`

Comment: Errrr no not really.  See my answer for a more direct approach.  Using `getline` repeatedly for this is overkill if you don't care about the other strings.  Plus you're calling it an extra time inside the loop, pointlessly clearing the result, and outputting the entire line.  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to use [`std::string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) as follows:

```
while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
{
    // Find position after last comma, extract the string following it and
    // add to the vector.  If no comma found and non-empty line, treat as
    // special case and add that too.
    std::string::size_type pos = line.rfind(',');
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        stringVector.push_back(line.substr(pos + 1));
    else if (!line.empty())
        stringVector.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: Hi @paddy Sorry for the late comments, but when I tried to run this part of the code it didn't work on Linux g++ compiler, but worked on visual studios 2017. Is there something that I need to add such as a library?

Comment: Read the error message.  If you don't understand the error message, post it.  Saying something "didn't work" is not how computer programmers speak, as it is meaningless.